# hibernate general problem

Tags: hibernate, schema, categories

Hi:
1)what is the difference between schema and a catalog?

That's to say in the cfg.xml,what is the meaning of `hibernate.default_schema` and `hibernate.default_catalog`?

2)how to handle the struture-same table?

I have ten tables in the db with the exact same structure,but the data is not.

For example:

I save some things in the `Data_1H` table like:

```
id       eventtime             ....
1        2010-01-02 12:00:00
2        2010-01-02 13:00:00
3        2010-01-02 14:00:00
```

And in the Data_2H table, I may save:

```
id       eventtime             ....
1        2010-01-02 12:23:00
2        2010-01-02 14:23:00
3        2010-01-02 16:23:00
```

So,I can  not merger the data,then I wonder I have to create ten java entities with same properties to mapping the ten tables in db?

Comment: Are you sure it's default_category and not default_catalog you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not heard of default_category. Check this table for all the available properties

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html